# Kali Linux Rolling: Trying to install Ruby 2.2.2 but getting "__rvm_make -j4" error

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, rvm, kali-linux

I'm pretty new to Linux systems and running Kali lite but I am trying to install Hashview and as per instructions, I have donwloaded RVM and the default version 2.4.0p0 is installed but I need 2.2.2 to match with the GEM file. When I attempt to install Ruby 2.2.2 I get the following error and I have tried on this machine and full Kali machine as well:

```
root@kali:~# rvm install ruby-2.2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: debian/Kali_Linux_Rolling/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for debian.
Installing requirements for debian.
Updating system.
Installing required packages: libreadline6-dev..
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.2 - #downloading ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.6M  100 12.6M    0     0   138k      0  0:01:33  0:01:33 --:--:-- 1314k
ruby-2.2.2 - #extracting ruby-2.2.2 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2....
ruby-2.2.2 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.2/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.2 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.2/openssl3.patch.
ruby-2.2.2 - #configuring......................................................|
ruby-2.2.2 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.2.2 - #compiling........................................................-
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1493066920_ruby-2.2.2/make.log
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
installing default pathname libraries
compiling objspace_dump.c
installing default nkf libraries
linking shared-object objspace.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/ext/objspace'
linking shared-object pathname.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/ext/pathname'
linking shared-object nkf.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/ext/nkf'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2'
uncommon.mk:189: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Can you post the full `log`...you can read it with `less /usr/local/rvm/log/1493066920_ruby-2.2.2/make.log`

Comment: How did you install RVM? Have you run `rvm get head` to make sure it's the current version? What does `rvm info` output? (Copy and paste the output into your question, formatted for readability.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm cleanup archives
```